# Python Saving JSON Files as UTF-8

Tags: python, json, utf-8, utf8-decode

I'm trying to output some UTF-8 characters to a JSON file.

When I save the file they're being written like this:

{"some_key": "Enviar invitaci\u00f3n privada"}

The above is valid and works. When I load the file and print 'some_key' it displays "Enviar invitación privada" in the terminal.

Is there anyway to write the JSON file with "some_key" as the encoded version, like this?

{"some_key": "Enviar invitación privada"}

Comment: Complete answer (including python 2 version) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337407/saving-utf-8-texts-with-json-dumps-as-utf8-not-as-u-escape-sequence).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Set `ensure_ascii` to `False`:

```
>>> print json.dumps(x, ensure_ascii=False)
{"some_key": "Enviar invitación privada"}
```

Comment: I'm still getting characters like: `Ã` instead of `à` `Ã¨` instead of `è` any suggestions?

Comment: This does not save the data to a file!

Answer (score 48):

Using Python 3.4.3 here and using `dump()` instead of `dumps()`:

```
    with open("example.json","w", encoding='utf-8') as jsonfile:
        json.dump(data,jsonfile,ensure_ascii=False)
```

is the standard way to write JSON to an UTF-8 encoded file.

If you want the escaped code points instead of the characters in your file, set `ensure_ascii=True`. 
This writes for example the Euro-character `€` as `\u20ac` directly to your file.